# How to fit dot graph with dot2tex(i)

Tags: tikz-pgf, dot2tex

Currently I used the `dot -Tpng` to include graphs in my LaTeX document. However it produced sometimes suboptimal graphics I wanted to look into `dot2tex(i)`.

The problem I encountered is that previously I could have something like:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{mygraph}
\caption{Description}
\label{fig:maxtoolchain}
\end{figure}
```

Now I tried

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{dot2tex}[dot]
\input{mygraph.dot}
\end{dot2tex}
\caption{Description}
\label{fig:maxtoolchain}
\end{figure}
```

However it produced very large graph - larger then the width of the page - even though the graph itself was very small. How to scale it back to `~0.4` of page width? (I've tried using `pgf` backend and it looks like `dot2tex` produce graph in bp units)

**EDIT** Small (not) working example:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{report}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{fullpage}
 \usepackage[pgf]{dot2texi}
 \begin{document}

 \begin{figure}[h!]
 \centering
 \begin{dot2tex}
 digraph G {
         A [label="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"];
         B [label="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"];
         C [label="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", shape=box];
         D [label="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"];
         E [label="XXX", shape=box];
         F [label="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"];
         G [label="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"];
         H [label="XXXXXXXXXXX", shape=box];
         I [label="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"];
         A -> C;
         B -> C;
         C -> D;
         D -> E;
         E -> F;
         F -> H;
         G -> H;
         H -> I;
 }
 \end{dot2tex}
 \end{figure}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Try to apply the options `x=1bp, y=1bp` to the resulting `tikzpicture`. The `dot2tex` package seems to allow `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1bp,y=1bp] \begin{dot2tex} … \end{dot2tex} \end{tikzpicture}`. Does this help you?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: No - I've just tried. From what I understand this sets the inner unit to 1bp - since dot2tex uses the explicit size in bp it does not affect it.

Comment: Ah, alright, I misunderstood you there. If you don’t want to use `scale`, then I propose the [`tikzscale`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzscale) package (it has a tag: [tag:tikzscale]) where you can specify (as usual with `\includegraphics`) the `width=.4\textwidth`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: I'll try `scale` then.